# Spectrum of circulant block matrix of circulant blocks (Adjacency matrix of discrete torus)

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices, spectral-graph-theory, cayley-graphs, circulant-matrices

I am currently investigating the spectrum of a matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{12 \times 12}$. The matrix has the following form,
$$ 
M = \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}.
$$

We can rewrite this matrix as $3 \times 3$ block matrix, where each block is in $\mathbb{R}^{4 \times 4}$. Then we have,
$$
M = 
        \left(
        \begin{array}{c|c|c}
       A & \mathbb{I}_{3} & \mathbb{I}_{3} \\
        \hline
        \mathbb{I}_{3} & A & \mathbb{I}_{3} \\
        \hline
        \mathbb{I}_{3} & \mathbb{I}_{3} & A \\
        \end{array}
        \right),
$$
where
$\mathbb{I}_{3}$ is the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix and $M \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$ is given by,
$$ M = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
Clearly, $M$ is circulant in block form and both $A$ and $\mathbb{I}_{3}$ are also circulant. However, $M$ itself is not a circulant matrix. Since $A$ and $\mathbb{I}_{3}$ we know that a orthonormal basis is given by the Fourier modes,
$$ v_j=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(1, \omega^j, \omega^{2 j}, \ldots, \omega^{(n-1) j}\right). \quad j=0,1, \ldots, n-1$$
where $\omega$ is the $n$-unit root, i.e., $\omega = e^{2\pi i/n}$. Since in our case $n=4$ we get that
$$ v_j=\frac{1}{2}\left(1, \omega^{1j}, \omega^{2j}, \omega^{3 j}\right). \quad j=0,1,2,3$$
are the eigenvectors of $A$ and $\mathbb{I}_{3}$. I believe I can construct $4$ of the eigenvectors of $M$ using the Fourier-modes $v_{j}$, $j=0,1,2,3$. Since a vector $w_{j}$
$$
w_j =\begin{bmatrix} v_{j} \\ v_{j} \\ v_{j} \end{bmatrix}, 
$$
is an eigenvector of $M$. This holds since,
$$ 
Aw_{j}= \left(
    \begin{array}{c|c|c}
   A & \mathbb{I}_{3} & \mathbb{I}_{3} \\
    \hline
    \mathbb{I}_{3} & A & \mathbb{I}_{3} \\
    \hline
    \mathbb{I}_{3} & \mathbb{I}_{3} & A \\
    \end{array}
    \right)
\begin{bmatrix} v_{j} \\ v_{j} \\ v_{j} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} Av_{j} + v_{j} + v_{j} \\ v_{j} + Av_{j} + v_{j} \\ v_{j} + v_{j} +Av_{j} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_{j}v_{j} + 2 v_{j} \\ \lambda_{j}v_{j} + 2 v_{j} \\ \lambda_{j}v_{j} + 2 v_{j} \end{bmatrix} = (\lambda_{j}v_{j} + 2 v_{j})\begin{bmatrix} v_{j} \\ v_{j} \\ v_{j} \end{bmatrix} = (\lambda_{j}v_{j} + 2 v_{j})w_{j} ,
$$
where $\lambda_{j}$ is the eigenvalue of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvector $v_{j}$. We observe that the vectors $w_{j}$ are no Fourier modes for $n=12$.

Observe, the $M$ is the adjacency matrix for the undirected Cayley graph of the group $\mathbb{Z}_{3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{4}$ generated by the set $\{ (1,0),(-1,0),(0,1),(0,1) \}$. Clearly $\mathbb{Z}_{3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{4} \simeq \mathbb{Z}_{12}$, and $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ is the cyclical group and the adjacency matrix of its Cayley graph is circular. Thus, I would imagine that the Fourier modes with $n=12$ are the eigenvectors of $M$. This seems inconsistent with the eigenvectors we constructed before.

Now to my questions:

Is there a way to calculate the entire spectrum of $M$? Are the Fourier modes also the eigenvectors of $M$ but with $n=12$? It would be helpful for me but does not seem to be the case. If they are not the eigenvectors, where am I going wrong in my second approach?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "is there a practical way to compute the eigenvectors" then you can simply ask your favorite programming language.

I used python's library sympy

> from sympy import * 
> A = Matrix([[0  ,  1  ,  0  ,  1  ,  1  ,  0  ,  0  ,  0  ,  1  ,  0  ,  0  ,  0 ],
> [1  ,  0  ,  1  ,  0  ,  0  ,  1  ,  0  ,  0  ,  0  ,  1  ,  0  ,  0 ],
> [0  ,  1  ,  0  ,  1  ,  0  ,  0  ,  1  ,  0  ,  0  ,  0  ,  1  ,  0 ],
> [1  ,  0  ,  1  ,  0  ,  0  ,  0  ,  0  ,  1  ,  0  ,  0  ,  0  ,  1 ],
> [1  ,  0  ,  0  ,  0  ,  0  ,  1  ,  0  ,  1  ,  1  ,  0  ,  0  ,  0 ],
> [0  ,  1  ,  0  ,  0  ,  1  ,  0  ,  1  ,  0  ,  0  ,  1  ,  0  ,  0 ],
> [0  ,  0  ,  1  ,  0  ,  0  ,  1  ,  0  ,  1  ,  0  ,  0  ,  1  ,  0 ],
> [0  ,  0  ,  0  ,  1  ,  1  ,  0  ,  1  ,  0  ,  0  ,  0  ,  0  ,  1 ],
> [1  ,  0  ,  0  ,  0  ,  1  ,  0  ,  0  ,  0  ,  0  ,  1  ,  0  ,  1 ],
> [0  ,  1  ,  0  ,  0  ,  0  ,  1  ,  0  ,  0  ,  1  ,  0  ,  1  ,  0 ],
> [0  ,  0  ,  1  ,  0  ,  0  ,  0  ,  1  ,  0  ,  0  ,  1  ,  0  ,  1 ],
> [0  ,  0  ,  0  ,  1  ,  0  ,  0  ,  0  ,  1  ,  1  ,  0  ,  1  ,  0 ]])
>
> A.eigenvects()

which returns

> [(-3,
> 2,
> [Matrix([
> [ 1],
> [-1],
> [ 1],
> [-1],
> [-1],
> [ 1],
> [-1],
> [ 1],
> [ 0],
> [ 0],
> [ 0],
> [ 0]]), 
> Matrix([
> [ 1],
> [-1],
> [ 1],
> [-1],
> [ 0],
> [ 0],
> [ 0],
> [ 0],
> [-1],
> [ 1],
> [-1],
> [ 1]])]), 
> (-1,
> 4,
> [Matrix([
> [ 1],
> [ 0],
> [-1],
> [ 0],
> [-1],
> [ 0],
> [ 1],
> [ 0],
> [ 0],
> [ 0],
> [ 0],
> [ 0]]), 
> Matrix([
> [ 0],
> [ 1],
> [ 0],
> [-1],
> [ 0],
> [-1],
> [ 0],
> [ 1],
> [ 0],
> [ 0],
> [ 0],
> [ 0]]), 
> Matrix([
> [ 1],
> [ 0],
> [-1],
> [ 0],
> [ 0],
> [ 0],
> [ 0],
> [ 0],
> [-1],
> [ 0],
> [ 1],
> [ 0]]), 
> Matrix([
> [ 0],
> [ 1],
> [ 0],
> [-1],
> [ 0],
> [ 0],
> [ 0],
> [ 0],
> [ 0],
> [-1],
> [ 0],
> [ 1]])]), 
> (0,
> 1,
> [Matrix([
> [-1],
> [ 1],
> [-1],
> [ 1],
> [-1],
> [ 1],
> [-1],
> [ 1],
> [-1],
> [ 1],
> [-1],
> [ 1]])]), 
> (1,
> 2,
> [Matrix([
> [-1],
> [-1],
> [-1],
> [-1],
> [ 1],
> [ 1],
> [ 1],
> [ 1],
> [ 0],
> [ 0],
> [ 0],
> [ 0]]), 
> Matrix([
> [-1],
> [-1],
> [-1],
> [-1],
> [ 0],
> [ 0],
> [ 0],
> [ 0],
> [ 1],
> [ 1],
> [ 1],
> [ 1]])]), 
> (2,
> 2,
> [Matrix([
> [-1],
> [ 0],
> [ 1],
> [ 0],
> [-1],
> [ 0],
> [ 1],
> [ 0],
> [-1],
> [ 0],
> [ 1],
> [ 0]]), 
> Matrix([
> [ 0],
> [-1],
> [ 0],
> [ 1],
> [ 0],
> [-1],
> [ 0],
> [ 1],
> [ 0],
> [-1],
> [ 0],
> [ 1]])]), 
> (4,
> 1,
> [Matrix([
> [1],
> [1],
> [1],
> [1],
> [1],
> [1],
> [1],
> [1],
> [1],
> [1],
> [1],
> [1]])])]

meaning that
$-3$ is an eigenvalue of multiplicity $2$ associated with the eigenvectors
\begin{pmatrix}1\\ -1\\  1\\ -1\\ -1\\  1\\ -1\\  1\\  0\\  0\\  0\\  0 \end{pmatrix} and \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ -1\\  1\\ -1\\  0\\  0\\  0\\  0\\ -1\\  1\\ -1\\  1 \end{pmatrix}

(and so on for the other lines)

It means that the spectrum is $S(M) = \{-3_2, -1_4, 0, 1_2,2_2,4\}$.

From a theoretical point of view, you could look for a $3 \times 3$ generalization of the lemma *"if $AC=CA$,  $\text{Det}\left( \begin{pmatrix}
 A & B\\
 C & D\\
\end{pmatrix}
\right) = \text{Det}\left( AD -CB \right)$".*

since you've got lots of identities matrices.